# mysql - set column value equal to insert id?

Tags: mysql

**Background:**

I have a database table which is for received_msgs

The table has two columns

`id`, `link_id`

If The message is the first one in there (based on criteria) then its `link_id` is equal to its `id`.

If it is a reply to a message, its `link_id` is equal to the `id` of the message it is in reply to.

---

**Question:**
is there any way on the initial insert to set `link_id` to be the same as the id?

At the moment I am doing the insert and then doing another query, an update, and setting the `link_id` to be equal to the `INSERT_ID`

But I dont like using two queries for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use trigger on `AFTER INSERT` action.

But I strongly recommend you to use `NULL` for the root of the adjacency list tree.

Comment: I agree. Avoid triggers. The `NULL`-approach is much cleaner.

Comment: `NULL` has the unfortunate drawback of being ignored by `UNIQUE` constraints

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT into your_table (id, link_id) values (ID, ID);
```

Comment: What is `ID` in your query? Where should OP get it?

Comment: The ID is the initial value for the id column. The OP wasn't clear if they were using an auto-increment value for the id column or not. If not, insert the generated id into both columns. If they are, I agree with the above, set link_id to null for the initial insert.